# How to make my floated <li>s expand to cover the whole <ul>?

Tags: css, css-float, html-lists

I decided to make my navigation links a styled-up `<ul>`. How can I make the width of each `<li>` expand so that they cover the entire `<ul>`, i.e. the first one starts at `left:0` and the last one ends at `right:0`?

How it looks at lower resolutions is not impor>tant. The red border is the `<ul>`, the blue one the surrounding `<div>`.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
div.nav_container {
    width:960px;
}
ul.nav {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
ul.nav li {
    margin:0 10px; padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:13%;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.nav li {
margin:0; padding:0;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
display: inline-block;
width: 158px;
background-color:white;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

Width of nav container (960px) divided by number of list items (6) = 160px minus 2px for border (1px each side) = li width of 158px.

Comment: Hm, I was trying to find a general solution, but now that I think of it, that would be quite silly as I do control the content and number of list items :)

Comment: Agreed, if the nav container wasn't a set width the solution would need to be different.